# Not able to login to Grails app

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am new to Grails.

I am trying to create web application called collab-todo by going through the book 'Begining groovy and grails from Novice to professsional'.
I am using dynamic scaffolding feature as,

```
class UserController {
   def scaffold = User
   def login = {}
}
```

In _topbar.gsp

```
<a href="/collab-todo/user/login">Login</a>
```

when I click the above Login link which is there in _topbar.gsp I am getting error like,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message:
Cannot invoke method list() on null object
```

my loging.gsp body,

```
 <body>
 <div class="body">
 <g:if test="${flash.message}">
 <div class="message">
 ${flash.message}
 </div>
 </g:if>
 <p>
 Welcome to Your ToDo List. Login below
 </p>
 <form action="handleLogin">

 <span class='nameClear'><label for="login">
 Sign In:
 </label>
 </span>
 <g:select name='userName' from="${User.list()}"
 optionKey="userName" optionValue="userName"></g:select>
 <br />
 <div class="buttons">
 <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit value="Login" />
 </span>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Looks like `User == null`

Comment: why it is null, i have created 2 users. if the framework is automatically reading values for the User Model.User.list()should contain some 2 values right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GSP page - renderer doesn't know what is `User`. You have 3 options:

1) User full class name (with package):

That is:

```
<g:select name='userName' from="${com.collabtodo.package.User.list()}" ... />
```

2) Import it:

```
<%@ page import="com.collabtodo.package.User"%>
...
<g:select name='userName' from="${User.list()}" ... />
```

3) Have it in your model:

```
import com.collabtodo.package.User
class TheController {
    def index() {
        [users: User.list()]
    }
}
```

in GSP:

```
<g:select name='userName' from="${users}" ... />
```

Comment: Option 3 should be listed first  since it's _crazy_ to do database calls from the view. This also makes it easier to limit the number of results returned, since you probably don't want to pull in a million user instances.